# Use sed to remove part of a line

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I remove with `sed` part of a line

```
захватывающее состязание смелых героинь и героев с профессионалами. &quot;}},&quot;has_video&quot;:1},&quot;trailer&quot;:{&quot;video_4_trailer&quot;:&quot;.(n).(n)</desc>
```

I want that part to be removed. I managed to remove the entire line but thats no what i need:

```
&quot;}},&quot;has_video&quot;:1},&quot;trailer&quot;:{&quot;video_4_trailer&quot;:&quot;.(n).(n)
```

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to edit a file in which this line occurs, or is it a text string in a shell script you want to process? Please edit your question to include that information. If it is a file, can this pattern occur on more than one line, and if so, do you want to remove it from every line it occurs on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pattern does not occur more than once on the line, and there is only one  `(n).(n)` part, the following should work:

```
sed 's/&quot;}}.*(n)\.(n)//'
```